# Recommended setting for Garbage collection in process intensive .net 4.5.2 WCF application

Tags: c#, wcf, garbage-collection, .net-4.5, garbage

I have the following settings in one of my .Net4.5.2 WCF application.

```
<runtime>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="true"/>
    <GCCpuGroup enabled="true"/>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

What correction is needed? My application processes 100 simultaneous requests.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question for clarification. Good luck!

Comment: When you don't have a concrete problem, no correction is required.